# Ruby on rails redirect upon login

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im following the tutorial on http://ruby.railstutorial.org

I've manage to get the part when user will get prompted to login when accessing a restricted page then be redirected back to the restricted page after logging in.

However, after the login, I've logged out and logged in with another user, i will get redirected back to the page, and not the default main page for a fresh session.

My session Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new

end

def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
   sign_in user
   redirect_back_or user
  # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
else
  # Create an error message and re-render the signin form.
  flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
end
end
....
end
```

My session helper

```
module SessionsHelper
....
def redirect_back_or(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  session.delete(:return_to)
end

def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
end

end
```

Comment: Where is `store_location` call?

Answer (score 0):

Add `session.delete(:return_to)` to create method

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    sign_in user
    session.delete(:return_to)
    redirect_back_or user
    # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
  else
    # Create an error message and re-render the signin form.
    flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```